# JPA: fetch field from child class in JOINED inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

my superclass is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_VEHICLE")
@ChangesListener
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "VEHICLE_ID"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "VEHICLE_TYPE_ID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Vehicle extends ParentEntity {
    @Column(name = "MAX_SPEED", nullable = false)
    private Integer maxSpeed;

    public Integer getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed(Integer maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

and subclass is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST_BUS")
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Bus extends Vehicle {
    @Column(name = "PASSENGER_NUMBER", nullable = false)
    private Short passengerNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_OF_VEHICLE")
    private Foo foo;

    public Short getPassengerNumber() {
        return passengerNumber;
    }

    public void setPassengerNumber(Short passengerNumber) {
        this.passengerNumber = passengerNumber;
    }

    public Foo getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

using fetch of `foo` on `Root<Vehicle>` in criteria:

```
root.fetch("foo", JoinType.LEFT);
```

causes this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [foo] on this ManagedType ...
```

how can I fetch fields from subclasses?

**update:**

using treat does not resolve my problem:

```
Root<Bus> busRoot = builder.treat(root, Bus.class);
busRoot.fetch("foo", JoinType.INNER);
```

I don't receive any error but foo does not fetch yet.
generated SQL is:

```
SELECT vehicle0_.VEHICLE_ID    AS VEHICLE_2_72_,
  vehicle0_.ATTACHMENT_COUNT   AS ATTACHME3_72_,
  vehicle0_.COMMENTS           AS COMMENTS4_72_,
  vehicle0_.CREATE_TIMESTAMP   AS CREATE_T5_72_,
  vehicle0_.CREATOR_USER_ID    AS CREATOR_8_72_,
  vehicle0_.MODIFIER_USER_ID   AS MODIFIER9_72_,
  vehicle0_.UPDATE_TIMESTAMP   AS UPDATE_T6_72_,
  vehicle0_.MAX_SPEED          AS MAX_SPEE7_72_,
  vehicle0_1_.FOO_OF_VEHICLE   AS FOO_OF_V3_70_,
  vehicle0_1_.PASSENGER_NUMBER AS PASSENGE1_70_,
  vehicle0_2_.ENGINE_TYPE      AS ENGINE_T1_71_,
  vehicle0_.VEHICLE_TYPE_ID    AS VEHICLE_1_72_
FROM TEST_VEHICLE vehicle0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_BUS vehicle0_1_
ON vehicle0_.VEHICLE_ID=vehicle0_1_.VEHICLE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_CAR vehicle0_2_
ON vehicle0_.VEHICLE_ID   =vehicle0_2_.VEHICLE_ID
WHERE vehicle0_.VEHICLE_ID=105
```

Comment: A Vehicle isn't necessarily a Bus; basic polymorphism. Cast things (treat) if wanting subclass field access, just like with basic java

Comment: Here is an extract from the JPA specification: ` The root objects of the query are entities, from which the other types are reached by nav-
igation.` That means either you move the `foo` to the `Vehicle` class or you make the `Bus` class the root of the query.

Comment: @NeilStockton yep. absolutely. but I want fetch foo field if it is Bus. like : `root.fetch("bus",JoinType.LEFT).fetch("foo", JoinType.LEFT);` but this solution does not work too.

Comment: As a basic question, must you use a `Discriminator` column? With an abstract base class I would have expected a `@MappedSupersclass`.

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, I need to create foreign key to SuperClass in some cases

Comment: As I understand it, discriminator columns aren't really meant for abstract classes. If it's abstract, it doesn't instantiate, so how can you have a foreign key to it?

Comment: @Nicholas In some case implementation is not significant, is not? And using JOINED strategy makes your superclass abstract in action, because you can not persist superclass lonely.  Also this problem still exists with removing abstract from class

Comment: If your problem still exists without abstract then see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide in stackoverflow.com and perhaps edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved using meta model.

```
public abstract class Bus_ extends com.rh.cores.architecture.tests.models.Vehicle_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Bus, Foo> foo;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Bus, Short> passengerNumber;
}
```

means this:

```
root.fetch(Bus_.foo, JoinType.LEFT);
```

but since fetch signature in JPA is like this:

```
<Y> Fetch<X, Y> fetch(SingularAttribute<? super X, Y> attribute, JoinType jt);
```

above code causes compile error!
with changing code like this:

```
SingularAttribute attribute = Bus_.foo;
root.fetch(attribute, JoinType.LEFT);
```

we can bypass generics check `SingularAttribute<? super X, Y>` in JPA standard while Hibernate handle it!